# Monitor locks over long period of time

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am having some issues with one of my tables in a production server.

I know there are many diffrent threads running on this table. I need to put some kind of monitoring tool to see how many locks are happening on this table, and which queries are causing this locks.

I am familiar of `slow-query-log`.

Are there any tools which can help me?  I have seen `monyog`, are there any free tools maybe?

Also is the a way to know all the deadlocks that happened overtime, like `show engine innodb status' deadlocks, but over time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

There is a variable called `innodb_print_all_deadlocks` which logs all the deadlocks in to the error log.